# If a group has an $a$ with $axa = x^{-1}$ for all $x$ then $y = y^{-1}$ for all $y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a multiplicative group with the identity element $e$, a fixed element $a \in G$ for which $axa = x^{-1}$, for all $x \in G$. Prove that $x = x^{-1}$.

I have already proved that $a = a^{-1}$ and $ax = (ax)^{-1}$, so using these can I say

$$ax = (ax)^{-1} = a^{-1}x^{-1}.$$

We know that $a = a^{-1}$ and so replacing this gives us

$$ax = ax^{-1},$$

which cancels down to give

$$x =x^{-1}.$$

Is that correct?

Comment: $(ax)^{-1} \ne a^{-1}x^{-1}$ unless $G$ is abelian. However, multiplying by $a^{-1}$ on the right gives $ax = x^{-1}a^{-1} = (ax)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conclude that $ax=(ax)^{-1}$, but not in general that $(ax)^{-1}=a^{-1}x^{-1}$ unless $G$ is abelian.

What you've shown, though, is that $(ax)^2=e$ for **every** $x\in G$. If we fix any $x_0\in G$, then, and let $x=ax_0,$ what can we conclude from $(ax)^2=e$, given that $a^2=e$?

Comment: $x_0^2 = e$? And so we get $x_0 = x_0^{-1}$?

Comment: Bingo! And since $x_0$ was arbitrarily chosen from $G$, then it holds for every element of $G$.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought. How can I conclude that $(ax)^2 = a^2x^2$? Using the fact that I don't know if $G$ is abelian, how can I say that $axax = aaxx = a^2x^2$?

Comment: You can't. However, $$e=(ax)^2=(a^2x_0)^2=(ex_0)^2=x_0^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

$ax = (ax)^{-1}$ - this is true. Further when $x$ runs over $G$ then $ax$ runs over $G$ too. If you denote $y=ax$ then you get $y=y^{-1}$ for all $y\in G$.

Comment: What do you mean by "when $x$ runs over $G$, then $ax$ runs over $G$ too"? Is this because as my original equation is true for any $x$, I can have $x = ay$, where $y \in G$?

Comment: @Kaish  I mean that $\{ax|x\in G\}=G$, so if you proved something for ALL $ax$, you get the proof for all $x\in G$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(ax)^{-1} = x^{-1} a^{-1}$, so your argument does not work as stated.

But since you have already proved that $(ax)^ 2 = e$ for all $x \in G$ (to get this it is of course enough to multiply by $x$ on the right the identity $a x a = x^{-1}$), just note that $x \mapsto a x$ is a bijection $G \to G$, so for all $y \in G$ you have $y^2 = e$, that is $y = y^{-1}$.

Comment: How do you get that $x \mapsto ax$? Also, how can you tell it's a bijection?

Comment: @Kaish: Make an educated guess for the inverse :).

Comment: So the inverse is the map that multiplies on the left by $a^{-1}$? How do you see that this map multiplies on the left by $a$ though?